# PHPStorm move file from one split to another

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, phpstorm

I have 2 vertical splits and I would like to move a file from one split to another using the keyboard.

Is there any way of doing this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any way of doing this?

Yes.

[image]

**P.S.**
You can assign any shortcuts you want to those actions in `Settings (Preferences on Mac) | Appearance & Behavior | Keymap`

Comment: Jackpot, thanks a ton! Added keyboard shortcuts to it, all good now!

Comment: @stats-hb What exactly does not work? It works for me in the latest 2022.3.1 version. Please show a screenshot of your setup (what files you have opened there and how) and the context menu for that file. The menu items will be different (esp names) though depending on if you have another split already or not etc. If I have 2 files opened in one split and 1 file in another then I can move that 2nd file to another split via context menu just fine (just different menu name now).

Comment: I just checked again and it does work.... sorry!

Answer (score 2):

This question and several similar ones pop out regularly in the case of members of the IntellijIdea family of IDE's. I've seen it asked for example in the case of AndroidStudio.

Using an IntellijIdea-based IDE there is a general solution for finding any command without leaving the keyboard, and that is `CTRL-SHIFT-a`.

As soon as the dialog appears, in the case of this question it's sufficient to type `move opp` and then you can already hit `ENTER` to have the command executed.